# compare current year and month to database entered y/m within sql query

Tags: php, mysql, date, select

Cannot write a complete function to compare current month and year to my database m/y.  The dates in the database are from the now() function.  I want to sum the costs based on this comparison.  Something like:

```
$currentDate = date("Y-m");
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT SUM(cost) FROM memberorders WHERE 
         memberNumber=$memNum AND 
        (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(orderDate, '%Y-%m'))=$currentDate");
```

But that's not working.  Then I need help with a function to sum it up.

```
$test1 = mysql_fetch_array($query);
$total = $test1[0];
```

Would that work for going through the database and summing it up?

Comment: Explain format of `$currentDate`.

Comment: No need to use inner select query. You can directly compare the dates. And What is the date format you were using?

Comment: I updated the post.  That current date displays today's year and month correctly.

Comment: @Saharsh I need a subquery because I don't want to compare the days.  Only sum the cost column if it's in the same month that we are in right now, if that makes sense

Comment: You can use the same date format function without inner query. Check my answer and try it

Comment: Query gives results month wise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that, don't apply any function (like the `DATE_FORMAT()` function) to a column (like the `OrderDate` column) if you want indexes to be used. Try this if you can create the fixed starts of months in the application (PHP) code:

```hs
SELECT SUM(cost) 
FROM memberorders 
WHERE memberNumber = $memNum 
  AND orderDate >= '2013-01-01'      -- first day of this month
  AND orderDate < '2013-02-01' ;     -- first day of next month
```

or this if you prefer to handle it in MySQL:

```hs
SELECT SUM(cost) 
FROM memberorders 
WHERE memberNumber = $memNum 
  AND orderDate >= LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY - INTERVAL 1 MONTH 
  AND orderDate < LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY ;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I don't know if I can use that.  I want to display the sum of the costs to the members on their member page.  So when a new month starts, it needs to reset.  It needs to be month to month so there is no end date

Comment: That's what it does. It sums all the costs of this month (January 2013). The first version needs some PHP code. The second version will work without any additional code.

Comment: and the second version will do that for every month?

Comment: For the current month. `NOW()` will return the current datetime, and the rest `LAST_DAY()` and stuff will calculate the required start and end (first day of this month and first day of next month). And it had a small error, it's corrected now.

Comment: dammit...i tried the code, changed it to just retrieve a value from the one row which is today's date and i get a mysql_fetch_assoc error...expects a parameter.
$query = ("SELECT * FROM memberorders WHERE orderDate >= (LAST_DAY(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 MONTH + INTERVAL 1 DAY) AND orderDate < (LAST_DAY(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
or is there something different I need to do to implement this function?

Comment: Sorry, nevermind...I forgot the mysql_query before the SELECT...been staring at the computer all day, making mistakes.  It works now.  I still don't really understand the function and how it works so I'm taking your word for it that it will work for when we get to the next month too.  Thanks

Comment: Try it, replacing `NOW()` (in both places) with `'2012-12-25'`. It will show you results for last December.